# Terminology for polynomials

Tags: polynomials

A multivariate polynomial in which the monomials have the same degree $d$ is called a homogeneous polynomial. An example for this is
$$ 11x^2y + 2y^3 + 9yz^2 + xyz.$$
Is there a notation for polynomials for the form
$$ 3x^3 + 7y^3 + 6z^3$$

Comment: What you wrote is **the** notation . The name can be two variables cubics.

Comment: "homogenous polynomial without cross-terms" is maybe more cumbersome than you want, but it gets the job done.